# How to brew install specific version of Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, homebrew, nvm

For example I want to install either 7.9 or 7.10 but want to avoid Node 8 due to the `webpack node-sass` breaking bug.

When I run `brew search node` this is what I see:

> ❯ brew search node
>   leafnode        llnode          node ✔          node-build      > node@0.10       node@0.12       node@4          node@6          nodebrew        nodeenv         nodenv
>   caskroom/cask/node-profiler
>
> If you meant "node" specifically:
>   It was migrated from caskroom/cask to homebrew/core.
>   You can access it again by running:
>     brew tap homebrew/core

There is node which is checked (my current version is `v7.4.0` then `node@0.10`, `node@0.12`, `node@4` and `node@6`?

The reason I can't just fully upgrade to 8 is node-sass won't work in webpack.

---

### Just installed NVM and got this crazy error log:

`=> nvm source string already in /Users/leongaban/.zshrc
=> Appending bash_completion source string to /Users/leongaban/.zshrc
npm ERR! missing: is-path-cwd@^1.0.0, required by del@3.0.0
npm ERR! missing: is-path-in-cwd@^1.0.0, required by del@3.0.0
npm ERR! missing: p-map@^1.1.1, required by del@3.0.0
npm ERR! missing: pify@^3.0.0, required by del@3.0.0
npm ERR! missing: rimraf@^2.2.8, required by del@3.0.0
npm ERR! missing: bluebird@^3.1.1, required by gulp-html-replace@1.6.2
npm ERR! missing: clone@^1.0.2, required by gulp-html-replace@1.6.2`

...

```
=> You currently have modules installed globally with `npm`. These will no
=> longer be linked to the active version of Node when you install a new node
=> with `nvm`; and they may (depending on how you construct your `$PATH`)
=> override the binaries of modules installed with `nvm`:
```

If I'm reading this right, does this mean I can't use `npm` to globally install packages anymore and have to use `nvm`?

#### Update

I added the export lines to my **.zshrc** bash (I don't use bash_profile)

```
❯ nvm --version
0.33.2
```

Comment: You can use https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: @MuradSofiyev so `nvm install node` then `nvm exec 7.9 node --version` ? I don't want to mess up the install and use version 8.

Comment: You can write thi command nvm install vYour want version and nvm use vYour want version

Comment: nvm install 7.9 
nvm use  7.9
You can also see this blog https://davidwalsh.name/nvm

Answer (score 202, accepted):

There are two ways in the decision for using different version of Node. *Second way* is more convenient and practical by my opinion (also may be faster).

---

### *First way:*

Install other Node version(for example 14) with using:

| `brew install` | `brew unlink` | `brew link` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| <kbd>[brew install - github](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/60afbd761a15bf1421cd5ce473ec7304cd9cff7d/docs/Manpage.md#install-formula)</kbd> | <kbd>[brew unlink - github](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/60afbd761a15bf1421cd5ce473ec7304cd9cff7d/docs/Manpage.md#unlink---dry-run-installed_formula-)</kbd> | <kbd>[brew link - github](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/60afbd761a15bf1421cd5ce473ec7304cd9cff7d/docs/Manpage.md#link-ln-options-installed_formula-)</kbd> |

```
brew install node@14
brew unlink node
brew link node@14
node -v
```

**PS** You may use `brew link` with flag  `--overwrite`, for example:

```
brew link --overwrite node@14
```

**PS2** Why `unlink` and then `link` again?

*Documentation:*

> Remove symlinks for formula from Homebrew's prefix. This can be
> useful for temporarily disabling a formula:
>
> `brew unlink formula && commands && brew link formula`

*In other words:*

if you have both node and node@14 installed, where node is other version(..,15 or 16), so, for set active version 14:

| you must `unlink` node | and then `link` to new installed version 14 |
| --- | --- |
| `brew unlink node` | `brew link node@14` |

---

### *Second way:*

Install Node Version Manager(nvm) and select Node version:

<kbd>[nvm - github](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)</kbd> <kbd>[nvm - home brew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/nvm)</kbd>

```
brew install nvm

mkdir ~/.nvm

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
    [ -s "$(brew --prefix)/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" ] && . "$(brew --prefix)/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
    [ -s "$(brew --prefix)/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm" ] && . "$(brew --prefix)/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm" # This loads nvm bash_completion

nvm install 14

nvm use 14

nvm list
```

Comment: FYSA - you need to use `--overwrite` flag for `brew link` if you've previously linked node via brew... see @sangamangre suggest - `brew link --overwrite node@14`

Comment: @SliverNinja-MSFT In my case it works without this flag

Comment: can you explain each command? why do you `unlink` and then `link` again?

Comment: @vsync I add why in PS2

Comment: Thank you! That worked, my nvim installation which was installed with node@18 was not working with copilot which requred <=17. This did the trick

Comment: this works but it is very slow to install node. I strongly recommend deleting all of node from brew and installing it with nvm

Comment: @FedericoCapaldo Ok, I add text that nvm may be faster

Comment: I installed node using the exact code, but after installation getting- zsh: command not found: node

Comment: @PratikshitSingh try add to file `vi ~/.zshrc` this 3 lines: 1) `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@14/bin:$PATH"` 2) 
`export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/node@14/lib"`
3) `export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/node@14/include"`

Answer (score 38):

If versions on `homebrew/code` are defined right, you must also be able to `brew install node@0.12` for example.

You can also install multiple versions and select which one you want to use with the `brew switch` command.

--

Anyway, I'd recommend using [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), which can be installed through Homebrew. Although, the version on `brew` is buggy and they don't plan fixing it.

Comment: Ok thanks, so if I go with nvm how do I decouple the version of node `7.4` on my machine which is currently installed via brew?

Comment: Would you mind a look at the new error messages I see right after installing nvm?

Comment: Ok so I installed `nvm` added those `export` lines to my .zshrc file, then did `nvm install v7.10` and now: `❯ node -v v7.10.0`
`❯ npm -v 4.2.0` `❯ nvm --version 0.33.2`

Comment: @LeonGaban sounds good, any other questions? Your packages are now separated for different versions of node. :)

Comment: I found this only works for the major version: `brew install node@10` works, but `brew install node@10.15` does not.

Comment: Yes, like @JJZabkar said there is no possible to choose specific version even version 11 is missing and now there is only 12.

Answer (score 27):

To install the latest version of node and unlink the previously installed

```
brew install node@14
brew unlink node
brew link --overwrite node@14
# Facing an issue with the brew link run below command and try again
# sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*  
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@14/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
node -v
```

Comment: support for zsh =>  `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/node@14/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`

Comment: If you find issues with linking on the `brew link` command, run `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*`and then try it again, worked for me

Answer (score -2):

```
brew install --build-from-source node@14
```

just use --build-from-source flag

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.