# How to Install Node version 14.18.2 Using Homebrew

Tags: node.js, homebrew, apple-m1

Using homebrew I am able to install node v12, v14, v16 and v17. But it seems to only install the latest stable version of each.

I am using an M1 Mac - any ideas on how to install node version 14.18.2 using homebrew?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to brew install specific version of Node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44803721/how-to-brew-install-specific-version-of-node)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of brew, you can use nvm to install and switch between different version of node.js on you Mac OSX :

https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm